# Xamarin EFCore SQLite Fluent API HasAlternateKey получение данных по альтернативному ключу

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, xamarin, fluent-interface

Всем доброго дня. Есть задача сделать базу для работы в смартфоне на SQLite. И она должна максимально быстро обрабатывать запрос, т.к. в таблице будет 1 314 000 строк.

К каждому часу в сутках будут привязаны остальные значения в строке.

Для этого хотел использовать поиск по ключу, что бы по нему сразу присваивать все остальные данные. Ключ в формате строки, в который переводится время.

Как сделать напрямую в xamarine через sqlite не нашел примера. Знаю, что without rowid, но не смог сделать запрос на создание таблицы без Primary Key.
Как альтернативу взял EFCore Fluent API HasAlternateKey.

Через метод альтернативного ключа получить всю строку в таблице по ключу.

Альтернативным ключем сделал Title.

Класс данных из примера

```
namespace EFGetStarted
{
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void 
OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasAlternateKey(a => a.Title);
    }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void 
OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite("Data 
Source=blogging.db");
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; } = new 
List<Post>();
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Обработчик из примера

```
namespace EFGetStarted
{
 class Program
 {
    public static string hu = "I wrote an app 
using EF Core!";
    static void Main()
    {

        using (var db = new BloggingContext())
        {
            // Create
            Console.WriteLine("Inserting a new 
blog");
            db.Add(new Blog { Url = 
"http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet" });
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Read
            Console.WriteLine("Querying for a 
blog");
            var blog = db.Blogs
                .OrderBy(b => b.BlogId)
                .First();

            // Update
            Console.WriteLine("Updating the 
blog and adding a post");
            blog.Url = 
"https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet";
            blog.Posts.Add(
                new Post
                {
                    Title = "Hello World",
                    Content = "I wrote an app 
using EF Core!"
                });
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Delete
            Console.WriteLine("Delete the 
blog");
            db.Remove(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // proba prisvaivanie

            var zapros= db.Posts.Single(a => a.Title == hu);
            //var tfg = db.Post.Single<Post>(a => a.Post == 1);

            string yhu= zapros.Content;
            Console.WriteLine(yhu);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот здесь моя попытка сделать поиск по альтернативному ключу Title и присвоить известное значение и вывести на консоль.

```
public static string hu = "I wrote an app 
using EF Core!";
// proba prisvaivanie

var zapros= db.Posts.Single(a => a.Title == hu);
string yhu= zapros.Content;
            Console.WriteLine(yhu);
```

Выдает ошибку

```
system.invalidoperationexception: "Sequence contains no elements"
```

Буду признателен за любую помощь. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Да к а в бд то у вас есть нужная вам строка? Судя по ошибке, вы ищете что то, чего в базе нет.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно. Буду разбираться.